# PHP Notice: Undefined offset: -1, while loop and PHP Fatal error: Out of memory

Tags: php, undefined, fatal-error, tree-traversal, out-of-memory

Well, as in the title, I am having a problem due to those things. The problem is occurring due to line X which is `while ($right[count($right)-1]<$row['rgt']) {` and this is in a function display_tree from [SitePoint's Tree Traversal](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/2).

The function was working well, but I don't know why it has suddenly started to throwing this fatal error.

I tried using `error_reporting(-1);` to understand what might be causing the error, and the new error log shows me that I'm getting the PHP Notice multiple time, as if in an unfinished loop, till a point where I am get that Out of memory error.

The weird thing is this was working perfectly till two days ago, since when I am pulling my hairs out to decipher what is causing the problem.

Any way to understand what is causing the problem exactly? or may be some other helpful tips?

Here is the while loop inside it's condition:

```
if (count($right)>0) {
$j=0;
while ($right[count($right)-1]<$row['rgt']) {  
  array_pop($right);
   $j++;
  }   
}
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: What is the point of the $j variable? Are you following the display_tree function completely?

Comment: Can you explain exactly how you want to list to come out?

Comment: Thanks Jacob, the problem is now solved, following awm's `while ($right && $right[count($right)-1]<$row['rgt']) {` and the extra nodes were part of a different problem that I solved. To answer your question, I am calling my list as `echo $tree->display_tree($id);` simply inside an ul or ol. Do you see anyway to improve the function, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, the notice `Undefined offset: -1` suggests that array `$right` is empty.

**Edit:** In your loop you're popping `$array` down to nothing... guaranteed to fail.  Need to stop the loop before the array becomes empty.

This will solve the immediate problem, but it's unlikely (by itself) to make your program work:

```
while ($right && $right[count($right)-1]<$row['rgt']) {
```

Since `end($right)` returns the same value `$right[count($right)-1]`, we can simplify this to:

```
while ($right && end($right) < $row['rgt']) {
```

Comment: Thanks awm. I did think about that, but the while loop is inside a condition. I'm editing my initial post to add that part of the code. Thanks for your reply again.

Comment: But you don't check if `count($right)` is 0, which it must be if `count($right)-1` is -1

Comment: You must include the `count()` in the `while` condition because you are modifying the array inside the loop. The `if` condition is only checked once before running the loop.

Comment: The purpose of the function is for MPTT trees, if the condition on this while loop fails, then there is something wrong with the tree.

Comment: @David `(bool) $right === (bool) count($right)` It's enough just to say `while ($right && ...`

Comment: Well, thanks guys for all the replies. `while ($right && $right[count($right)-1]<$row['rgt']) {` has stopped the fatal error. However, this is changing the result of my tree (I'm getting more than what I should). Some nodes outside of $founder is appearing in the resulting tree.

Comment: I think this is called treating the symptoms rather than the cause... ;)

Comment: I agree awm that we should treat the cause. It's elsewhere, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are following Site Points function completely, I imagine the reason for the error is that your tree is corrupt.

Even more reason to suggest your tree is corrupt, is that you say the code was working fine a few days ago...

I've testing your function on the Site Point tree and it seems to run fine.

The function doesn't do any checking for a corrupt tree. The while loop condition you first pointed out should never reach a situation where $right is empty.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I did do some minor changes to the sitepoint function, to meed my specific needs. I'm adding the full function by editing my initial post. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I have posted the full function on my initial post. Can you point me out something please (which part you saw corrupt in SP's function ) ?

Comment: There is nothing corrupt in the function. The tree in your database is most likely corrupt.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. If you see anyway to improve my function (on my initial post), I will welcome your comments. For the errors, it is now solved using [awm's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/607514/awm) `while ($right && $right[count($right)-1]<$row['rgt']) {`